# Sum columns in a pandas dataframe which contain a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I am trying to do something relatively simple in summing all columns in a pandas dataframe that contain a certain string.  Then making that a new column in the dataframe from the sum.  These columns are all numeric float values...

I can get the list of columns which contain the string I want

`StmCol = [col for col in cdf.columns if 'Stm_Rate' in col]`

But when I try to sum them using: 
`cdf['PadStm'] = cdf[StmCol].sum()`

I get a new column full of "nan" values.

Comment: Need a [mcve] please! With some data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in [axis=1 to `.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html), by default (axis=0) sums over each column:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["A", "B"])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [13]: df[["A"]].sum()  # Here I'm passing the list of columns ["A"]
Out[13]:
A    4
dtype: int64

In [14]: df[["A"]].sum(axis=1)
Out[14]:
0    1
1    3
dtype: int64
```

Only the latter matches the index of df:

```
In [15]: df["C"] = df[["A"]].sum()

In [16]: df["D"] = df[["A"]].sum(axis=1)

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   A  B   C  D
0  1  2 NaN  1
1  3  4 NaN  3
```